# Save *everything* across sessions

Tags: history, session

When I quit Emacs, nothing is saved, such as my search history, my command history, my replace strings, etc.

I want EVERYTHING saved.  How do I do that?

And by everything, I mean at least the following;

- Cursor, I mean, point :) position in each file Undo history for each
  file
- Command history. This is tricky to specify because unlike in the
  other editor, commands are issued in various ways. C-x, etc. M-x,
  etc.
- Search and replace history

It should feel as if I never exited the session.

I do not even know where to look for.  Google shows me some scary cryptic functions, etc. And talks about packages, etc.

Is there an easy, newbie friendly way out?

Comment: Start with [`desktop-save-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html).

Comment: "Everything" covers a lot of ground.  Please specify what you really want saved -- you'll probably get more helpful answers that way.

Comment: @Dan edited the question. It should feel as if I never exited the session

Comment: I could be wrong, but I doubt there's a single package that is going to get you "everything," which, again, is very broad.  You will probably get better answers if you can narrow it down to the things you REALLY want and ask about those, rather than just say "everything."

Comment: Alternatively, don't quit your session ;0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you should start, as others have said, by getting to know (well) `desktop.el`. Add to that `savehist.el` and `saveplace.el`.  Others may have other suggestions.

`savehist.el` will take care of histories and rings (they are variables), including command histories (`command-history`, `extended-command-history` ...).